# Can't get Sass to work for a website project. Script crashes with npm run sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I am trying to use node sass for creating a website in visual studio. I follow a Guide and in there it says Sass is used to auto create .CSS files. SASS is used as a way to compile down .scss files to .css files. 
However, after the installation of npm  and trying to run a script with Sass I always get this error message:

```
n1c0@nico-linux:~/Documents/modern_portfolio$ npm run sass

> modern_portfolio@1.0.0 sass /home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio
> node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive

internal/fs/utils.js:220
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'scss/'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:922:3)
    at Object.module.exports.parseDir (/home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio/node_modules/sass-graph/sass-graph.js:153:10)
    at Object.watcher.reset (/home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/lib/watcher.js:17:21)
    at watch (/home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:260:20)
    at run (/home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:319:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/n1c0/Documents/modern_portfolio/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:405:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'scss/'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! modern_portfolio@1.0.0 sass: `node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the modern_portfolio@1.0.0 sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/n1c0/.npm/_logs/2019-11-29T19_29_28_755Z-debug.log
```

First Step I did was getting the "package-json" manifest with `npm init` command and then I installed node-sass with the `npm install node-sass` command. The installation went fine, so I went ahead and set up the package.json so that I can call the script and get it to work. 
However, this is were it fails every time.

**My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and the commands for the versions give back:
npm -v: 6.13.1
node-v: v13.2.0**

I tried the process several times, I also reinstalled npm and node and tried it with other versions, but always the same error.
I am new to Linux so maybe I messed something up with the OS, but I have no clue what to do or how to fix this. 
I searched this forum and there are some threads with this problem, some of them got it fixed somehow but for me all the suggested commands are not working.

Would be happy if somebody could look into this and unscramble my brian and help with the problem.

Worst case scenario I will reinstall Ubuntu because I just don't know what else to do.

Regards

---

[The File Tree of my project, the error is mentioning some erorr with "no such directory as scss" or something along those lines, but there is a folder with that name in the project folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plXy4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scss/` folder is inside `dist/`, so your command should be: `node-sass -w dist/scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 5 minutes after publishing the post I found the answer. The script had a wrong path and could find the scss folder so the only thing I had to do was adding another folder to it.

So I had to run this: 
"sass": "node-sass -w dist/scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive" 
insted of
"sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive"

Sorry for this, I thought I was going insane, but I finally fixed it.